# If $\nvDash\phi$ must it be $\vDash\lnot\phi$? If $\nvDash\phi$ where $\phi$ first order sentence must it be $\vDash\lnot\phi$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I got stuck at this problem:

> Determine whether the following sentences are true or false in first order logic:
>
> (1) If $\nvDash\phi$ must it be the case that $\vDash\lnot\phi$?
>
> (2) If $\nvDash\phi$ where $\phi$ is a first order sentence must it be the case that $\vDash\lnot\phi$?

I am stucked when I try solve this problem and
I am not sure I am fully understand those symbols when it comes to first order logic.

Thanks for any hint or help.

Comment: **NO** : neither $\forall x P(x)$ nor $\lnot \forall x P(x)$ are *valid* f-o sentences.

Comment: For a counter-example, consider the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers and interpret $P(x)$ first as $x > 0$ (it falsify the first sentence) and then as $x \ge 0$ (it falsify the second one).

Comment: What $\vDash\phi$ and $\nvDash\phi$ means when it comes to First Order Logic? (In propositional logic it just means that $\phi$ is a tautology / not tautology correspondingly but when it comes to first order Logic I am not sure what it means).

Comment: It means *valid* :  $\vDash \varphi$ iff $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi$, for any "appropriate" *structure* $\mathfrak A$. And for a sentence $\varphi$, we have $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi$ if the structure *satisfy* $\varphi$ according to the semantical clauses for the satisfaction relation.

Comment: And what $\vDash \phi$ means when the formula $\phi$ has free variables?

Comment: For formulae with free vars we have two options : (i) use a *variable assignment* function $s : Var \to A$, where $A$ is the domain of the structure $\mathfrak A$, and define recursively : $\mathfrak A$ *satisfy* $\varphi$ with $s$ [$\mathfrak A, s \vDash \varphi$], or (ii) define $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi$, with $\varphi$ with $x$ free, as $\mathfrak A \vDash \forall x \varphi$.